# Why is it opening the link in external browser in android app when implemented using ionic InApp browser

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, browser, ionic3, inappbrowser

I am trying to open a URL from ionic application, for which I have implemented InApp Browser, but its opening the URL in external browser of mobile, it should open the browser inside the application. Not sure where am I going wrong. Below is the code I tried, any guidance in this regard is much helpful, thank you..

```
openUrl(){
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  let url='http://192.168.0.7:8000/pay;
  const browser = this.iab.create(url, '_blank', 
  'hidden=yes,location=yes,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes');
  });
 // Inject scripts, css and more with browser.X
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me.

```
  openUrl(){
    let url='http://192.168.0.7:8000/pay';
    const browser = this.iab.create(url, '_blank', 
      'hidden=no,location=yes,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes');
    browser.show();
  }
```

**Notice:**
 1. hidden=no
 2. browser.show()

**And this is the result:**
[image: inAppBrowser Example]

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it is not working even on adding open.

Comment: Let me give it a try, I will get back to you

Comment: this works for me ..

  openUrl(){
   let url='http://192.168.0.7:8000/pay';
   const browser = this.iab.create(url, '_blank');
   browser.show();
  }